# add and remove a certain value from a text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

each checkbox that i check, i fill the input with it's `id`

now, how can i retrieve this `id` that i put inside the input if the user uncheck the checkbox?

exp:

estate `SC`,`SP` was checked;

`input` recieve `SC`,`SP` value in this format = **SC,SP**

but the user uncheck the checkbox with SC value, then `SC` should be removed from the input.

this is what i'm doing to fill the input with the checkboxes.

```
var separador = ",";
var estadosS  = "";
$(".checkboxEstados").live("click", function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        estadosS += (estadosS == "") ? "" : separador;
        estadosS += $(this).attr("id");
        $("#holdEstados").val(estadosS);
    }else{
        // now i'm just cleaning all the input, 
        // but i need to clean only the checkbox that was unchecked
        $("#holdEstados").val(""); 
    }
});
```

dont know if i was clear, any question, be my guest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're logic can be greatly simplified. Simply grab each checkbox that is checked when the click event fires:

```
$(".checkboxEstados").live("click", function() {
    var aryIds = new Array();

    $(".checkboxEstados:checked").each(function() {
        aryIds.push($(this).attr("id"));
    });

    $("#holdEstados").val(aryIds.toString());
});
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/2pjrP/).

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to solve this is to avoid parsing and removing parts of the data. Instead of trying to remove 'SC', instead regenerate the entire contents of the text field each time any checkbox is selected.

When a checkbox click event is detected, deleted the contents of the text input field, scan all of the selected checkboxes, and include their IDs in the text input field.

Comment: this is by far the best way (unless you have thousands of checkboxes which could be a bit slow), you're getting yourself into some nasty string manipulation otherwise

Comment: @George Cummins: oh, looks like a nice way to solve the problem. will try something like that.

Comment: @RicardoArruda, My answer and corresponding fiddle provides an example of this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the value in an array and add and remove values from it and then write the array to the output instead of trying to parse the text each time:

```
var estadosS = [];

$(".checkboxEstados").live("click", function(){
    var index;

    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        // append the id to the list
        estadosS.push($(this).attr("id"));
    }else{
        index = estadosS.indexOf($(this).attr("id"));

        if(index > -1) {
            estadosS.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }

    $("#holdEstados").val(estadosS.join(separador));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If all you are aiming to do is get a list of the checked values from all the check boxes, you could do:

```
$('.checkboxEstados:checked').each(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

And that should return all the check box items that have been checked. Then you don't have to worry about adding and removing data from a text box. I'm just alerting the value, you would want to store them into an object or something more useful.